# Changing Qty of SOLine from a Different Page

Tags: acumatica

I have a customization in which the user can adjust the quantity of an SO Line from a different page. This works perfectly, except when the user goes to execute the action "Create Shipment" for that SO. When "Create Shipment" executes, the shipment record created reflects the original values the user put in for the line's quantity instead of the adjusted quantity. Here is an example:

I created an order with original SO quantities of 10 and one respectively. I then changed the quantities to 8 and 5 respectively through my customization page:
[image]

This is the shipment I get when I select Actions -> Create Shipment:
[image]

I have looked through and adjusted any numbers misrepresenting the values I desired in the SQL tables SOOrder, SOLine, and SOLineSplit, but I still get the incorrect values when creating a shipment. Is there a table I am missing?

Comment: How are you updating the line quantity? I would suggest changing the sales qty from your custom page using the SOOrderEntry graph and not just an update of SOLine directly (in case that is what you are doing). It could also be a cache issue? (process sees old values stored in cache vs querying for the new values)

Comment: I am changing it directly using the SOLine instead of creating an instance and changing the value that way. I did think about using an SOEntry instance, but I wanted to see if there were other ways I could do it first.

Comment: that might be ok - I would just include all of the parents/child Dacs as view to such SOOrder and SOLineSplit. Does your custom page call the create shipment process? or is the user going to a different page for this? does the user try to refresh before running the process? (thinking it might be a cache not updated issue)

Comment: The user still creates the shipment through the SO page. I made sure to refresh the SO page before calling create shipment but still got the old values. I'm still curious as to how the shipment is being set to the original values when all of the tables I know of associated with the SO Line Qty are changed to the new values.

Comment: What about the related INitemPlan for the sales line? (joined on PlanID between the two tables). The INItemPlan i think is used for the shipment creation and contains a PlanQty field. does it have the old values?

Comment: The INItemPlan table  was what I needed to update. I had no idea that table was linked to the SO line. I did see the "PlanID" before but had no idea what that was associated to. Thanks Brendan!

Comment: all of inventory will drive a plan which supports the quantity available/on hand numbers. My guess is if you used the SOOrderEntry graph, the plan record would auto update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the issue could be the PlanQty found on the related `INItemPlan` record which the Create Shipment process uses to create the shipment.

Might be worth looking into getting the SOLine updated via the SOOrderEntry graph or make sure the INItemPlan values are getting updated correctly. Maybe a missing view in your custom page. I think the values are updated from the attribute on PlanID of SOLineSplit if that helps.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I believe I needed to was update that table. I created a view, fetched the entry, and it worked.